# Why can't I simply push 1 file to my repo without having to do a git pull?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have my remote server, Bitbucket repo and my local repo. When I want to change a certain file, I change it in my local repo and then `git add <file_name>`/`git commit -m "file changed"` and then `git push` to my Bitbucket repo. I then get the following errors:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I then do `git push --set-upstream origin master` and get these errors:

```
To https://bitbucket.org/user/name.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://user@bitbucket.org/user/name.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I don't want to do `git pull` because my local repo is different from the Bitbucket repo and the Bitbucket repo is for production and the local repo is for development do they're different. All I want to do is simply update single files in my Bitbucket repo by changing them locally and simply doing `git add <updated_file>`/`git commit`. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Related XKCD: https://xkcd.com/1597/

Comment: Are you using separate branches for development and production, or are you just cramming everything into the same branch?

Comment: Cramming everything

Comment: If you want to reflect different environments, using forks (synced or not) or branches can be beneficial. But if the code is *different* based on local or remote, why do you expect to be able to just push code willy-nilly?

Comment: The git hint tells you exactly why. In a multi-user development env. you cannot say i only want to push my change and not take anyone else's changes. Some one has to do the merge changes by multiple developers, and resolve any merge conflicts - and it ain't git. Unless you want to work in a world (branch/fork) of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can not push a single file without `git pull`.

Since git will calculate if all the sha-1 values from the remote branch which you are trying to push are existing in your local repo, and then decide whether it can be pushed or rejected.
As you found, if you push to remote without `git pull`, git will reject to push.

And there are two options you can follow:

#### Option1: stash the file you changed and apply the changed file on the top of latest version

You can use below commands to achieve:

```
git reset head~
git stash -- filename
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
git statsh apply
git push -u origin master
```

Then only the `filename` is pushed to remote `master` branch.

#### Option2: force push

You can force push the local `master` to remote `master` branch by `git push -f origin master` or push to a new branch.